# lag in GUI created in Qt (verified by QTime)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a GUI C++ `Class` in Qt which has a `SLOT` which adds an array of Text box's & label's in a `QGridLayout`. The array is square depending upon a variable say `n`. i.e. if `n == 10` then there are `10x10` `QTextbox` & `QLabel` in the `QGridLayout`. Basically when a user presses the *Increase button* the value of `n` is incremented by 1 & accordingly the `QTextbox` & `QLabel` are created in a `SLOT` & added in the `QGridLayout`. When the value of `n` is `15` it is taking **1-2** *secs* for the GUI to be updated. However when I used `QTime` in that `SLOT` it showed me that the actual time to execute that `SLOT` is about **100** *ms*. While in *Debug* mode I observed that `QDebug` used to print the elapsed time even though the GUI wasn't completely updated for higher values of `n`. I would like to know why is there so much delay & what is running after that `SLOT` is executed so that I can measure the time for the same. I hope I made myself clear. Please let me know if you could not understand my Question.
Thank You.

Actually I don't have the exact code with me right now. So I have created a sample code highlighting the logic of my code. Please ignore any syntax errors as I have prepared it as quickly as I could. Sorry for that :(
So here's the code snippet:

```
Class A
{
private:
    int n;
    QList <QLabel *> *labelList;
    QList <QTextEdit *> *textList;
    QGridLayout *inp;

    public slots:
        updateGUI();
}

A::updateGUI()
{
    QTime t;
    t.start();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
                            int even = j%2;
            QLabel *tempLab = new QLabel();
            //some stuff for initialisation of the QLabel
            QTextEdit *tempText = new QTextEdit();
            //some stuff for initialisation of the QTextEdit
            labelList->append(tempLab);
            textList->append(tempText);
                            if(even == 0)
                inp->AddWidget(tempLab, i, j, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
            else
                                inp->AddWidget(tempText, i, j, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
        }
    }

    QDebug("%d", t.elapsed());
}
```

PS: `QTime tobj.start()` is the 1st line in the `SLOT` & `QDebug("%d", tobj.elapsed())` is the last line in the `SLOT` Ofcourse!

Comment: I'd say try using a profiler like valgrind+callgrind+kcachegrind, or whatever's good on your platform (which by the way you should mention!).

Comment: Impossible to tell without more details (code would be nice). As is, I'd be tempted to point out that 15 * 100ms is 1.5 secs, but it's not clear how many times you're calling that slot. You're not supposed to do long processing in the UI thread.

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry! Its Win7 64 & Qt Creator 4.8.1

Comment: @Mat the SLOT adds all the elements in 1 call i.e. there is a for loop in the SLOT & it runs depending upon the value of n.

Comment: The slot probably does not force a repaint and thus the time to actually draw the widget is not included. You could maybe try overriding `QWidget::drawEvent` (or something similar) and measure that time

Comment: An alternate approach is to call `QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents )` at the end of your slot and measure that. That forces any pending events (like the repaint, but also others) to be processed before the `processEvents()` call returns. My first suggestion probably is more effective though.

Comment: I am actually a beginner in Qt & dont exactly know what that event is. In the SLOT I have only created the QTextbox & QLabel & added each one of them to the GridLayout.... Am I supposed to update the GUI paint stuff myself or does Qt handle that stuff?

Comment: show the slot which is executed when the user press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.1s delay is because you are creating a ton of widgets and then adding them to a grid (every time you add a widget, which obviously has an overhead, the dimensions of the other cells have to be updated as things 'shuffle' round).

So why the further delay after the timer?  All the painting and resizing events that were generated by the slot have now been put into the event queue, which was halted whilst your slot was executing.  Once your slot completes, all those tasks need to be processed.

Further to what other people have said, there are two fundamental flaws to what you are doing:

- Deleting all the existing widgets to add possibly a single one.  I didn't think I need to explain how horribly inefficient this is...
- If you have managed to get into the situation where **100s** of text boxes and labels in a grid are being shown to the user - *your UI has failed.*  You need to come up with a better way of allowing the user to interact with all this data.

Comment: Thank You @cmannett85! I found your answer most satisfying. I will change the algorithm so that only the required items are added & old are'nt deleted. Regarding your "UI has failed" comment, I would like to ask you then what would the better UI?
 The objective of my program is to take the co-efficients of Simultaneous Equations to solve them. The QLabel are used to identify the variable & QTextEdit is used to input double values. In a situation where the user wants to solve equations with 100 variables say, the UX will be inevitably bad...
Do you have a better suggestion?
Thanks again! :)

Comment: "If you have managed to get into the situation where 100s of text boxes and labels in a grid are being shown to the user - your UI has failed". The creators and users of Lotus-1-2-3 and Excel might disagree.

Comment: @MSalters I see your point, but the equivalent of their `QTableView` looks nothing like a grid of `QLabel`s and `QTextEdit`s.

Comment: @CAD_coding The structure of a simultaneous equation is quite regular, so the coefficients can be parsed quite easily - look at how this website has done it: http://www.webmath.com/solver2.html  You could also try posting on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ for other ideas.

Comment: @cmannett85 but that website's solver is for only 2 variables! It cannot accomodate more than say 5 variables. for the case of variables < 4, my layout looks quite clean & user friendly, but for more variables, the width of screen is not sufficient so the user has to scroll horozontally....
But I think there has to be a tradeoff for more variables.
What do you say?

Comment: @CAD_coding If I understand the problem correctly you will only need 1 box per equation: The equations can be parsed into their component coefficients easily (each coefficient is separated by a basic numerical operator).  Also the variables will be the only letters that appear in each equation, meaning they can be parsed easily (you have already split the equation into coefficients, so now split off the letters from the coefficients).  This can be done in one operation if you have some l33t RegExp skillz.

Comment: No, the label specifies the variable: ex: "x1", "x2", etc. & the textbox next to that label is to take the co-efficient for the variable. Since the code above is just a snipet, I didnt show that I also have textboxe's for "+" between 2 variables & a "=" label just before the textbox for RHS value.
what you are suggesting is that the user should type "3a + 4b = 5", correct?
If so, I didnt want the user to type unnecessary stuff so I made this UI.

Comment: @CAD_coding But you have replaced the "unnecessary stuff" with more GUI components making it hard to read and less compact.  Also people can type "3a + 4b = 5" into a single text box much faster than they type the individual bits into various ones.  Post your concerns on ux.stackexchange.com and people more knowledgeable than you or I can give their opinion.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing a bulk update on a widget, turn off [the updatesEnabled property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop). This prevents 21 individual updates when you're adding (11*11-10*10) new buttons.

Comment: Actually my current algo is that whenever that Increase button is pushed I am delete ing the existing GUI & creating fresh items. So say n = 10 the there are 100 QTextEdit & 100 QLabel, when button is pressed:
1. delete those 200 items
2. n = 11
3. add the 121 * 2 items.

Comment: @CAD_coding: So that would be 221 changes instead of 21. Even more reason to suppress updates during that period.

Comment: yup I plan to change that , thats not my main problem right now. my problem is that adding 242 items is taking more time even after execution of my code which takes about 100 millisecs!

Comment: that's the reason your code is taking that much time, so that's your problem right now.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Made some idiotic mistake in that algorithm. I will do the necessary changes... :)

Answer (score 1):

It would really help, if you post some code with the same problem. How will your slot react, when you select let's say n=10 and then n=7? Does it removes 3 last items from layout? And if you select n=7 and then n=10, will it try add only last 3 lines?
Is it possible, that you are not removing items from layout and trying to add new items over the existing ones?

If it is so - then you can remove all widgets from layout with this:

```
QLayoutItem* item;
while ( ( item = %your_layout_name%->takeAt( 0 ) ) != NULL ){
    delete item->widget();
}
delete item;
```

or you can remove widget by it's object name (or by handle, stored in QList QVector or something):

```
swLayout->removeWidget(myTextEdit);
```

UPD:
now, that we have some code,
you also need to clear labelList and textList, which store handles if i'm correct.
Then, lines

```
inp->AddWidget(tempLab, i, j, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
inp->AddWidget(tempText, i, j, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

tries to  add tempLab widget to layout inp in position (i,j) with 5 height and width, then you try to add another widget tempText to the same location, which is obviously wrong

Next, the loop itself is incorrect:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
```

is you make a loop like this, then you will be adding widgets like this:

```
inp->AddWidget(tempLab, i, 0, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
inp->AddWidget(tempLab, i, 1, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
inp->AddWidget(tempLab, i, n, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

but you sat widget width and heigth as 5, so you need to add widgets another way or they will be painted over each other:

```
inp->AddWidget(tempText, i*5, j*5, 5, 5, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have already cleared that doubt in my comment to MSalters. i.e. I am delete ing all the existing label's & text edit's (but this is not in this SLOT!), then I am updating the value of n & finally I am calling this SLOT. Hope that clears some doubts!

Comment: this is not width and height, it is row span and column span.

Comment: yeah, i know it, sorry, bad choice of words

Comment: @Shf i think you got me all wrong. My code is adding an array of elemets sort of like a 2D table & it is perfectly adding elements at the required spot & there is no 1 on top of other widget at all!!
Plus let me remind you that the SLOT is only for adding the widgets!
When the user presses the button the following things happen:
1. delete existing widgets using the pointers from the QList & remove them from the QGridLayout
2. update the value of n
3. call SLOT updateGUI
 I think the coding doesnt have logical errors (except for the one pointed by MSalters)
So can you now tell me why the delay?

Comment: ok, I even checked this in the test app myself. The code, you presented results in this - http://i.imgur.com/9UKFdee.jpg

I started checking errors with obvious syntax errors, before looking for logical errors.

Comment: I icreased n to 40. There was a little difference if `setUpdatesEnabled` was set to false before adding items to layout, and true afterwards, (601 instead of 621) and like you said - there was about a second delay of showing form after message appeared in debug. I still think, that there is an error in layout.

Comment: As for logical errors - algorithm is bad. Istead of removing everything and then creating the same objects again and repainting them, you should remove or add just the necessary. If n changes from 10 to 3, you should remove just 3 last rows and columns, and the same goes the other way, just add 3 rows and cols at the end if it goes from 7 to 10, etc. Yeah, swithing `setUpdatesEnabled` to false before updates also helps, but mostly - it's bad algorithm. IF the layout is set correctly as you say

Comment: @Shf sorry for the delay!
Actually the code previously was a bit incorrect (sorry for that as I was in college & my laptop wasnt with me). I have updated the code. Yes I agree that the current algorithm is bad & I will surely correct that. But as you also found that there is a lag in displaying the graphics & execution of SLOT (as shown by QTime in Qdebug). So what do you think is the reason for that?